# touchpad works even when i disable it on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: touchpad, 22.04

Recently I upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 but when I disable my touchpad in settings, it still works. I didn't have this problem on ubuntu 21.10.

I can disable it by `fn+f6` but this isn't permanent. I want to disable it completely not on each startup.

[image]

Comment: So to be clear, setting the switch next to "Touchpad" does not have any effect, whereas it has effect with fn+F6, but does not persist between reboots? You may also want to add some information about your hardware.

Comment: yes exactly. disabling touchpad in setting has no effect

Comment: can you not deactivate in Bios/Uefi menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable the Synaptics touchpad driver, then reboot.

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

I had installed the driver to get rid of  some erratic behavior due to too high touchpad sensitivity like random text selection etc. However, when I tried to disable the mouse it was not disabled as in your case. Deinstallation helped in my case.